# The connection has timed out when access remote machine port

Tags: port, windows-server-2019, eventstoredb

I install eventstore db on remote machine and I run it with command

```
EventStore.ClusterNode.exe --db ./db --log ./logs --insecure
```

Locally on `http://localhost:2113` I can acknowledge that DB is running and DB ui is available.

However, I want to enable access to this port 2113 from the outside so I open ports 1113 and 2113 on remote machine firewall but I still cannot access db interface using `http://my-remote-ip.com:2113`. Getting `The connection has timed out`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either

- routing of network traffic between the client & the server is not set up

  - typically some natting issue :
    https://developers.eventstore.com/server/v21.10/networking.html#network-address-translation

Or

- a configuration issue :

  - `ExtIp` probably need to be bound to the IP ( https://developers.eventstore.com/server/v21.10/networking.html#external)

this should help you set the configuration correctly https://configurator.eventstore.com/